# GWT - get image from byte array

Tags: gwt, base64

I tried [this code](http://sahers.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/gwt-base64-decoding-into-binary-supports-unsigned-byte-data/) to decode base64 image to binary; the thing I want to get image of the byte array on client... I am not pretty sure how to create image of byte array on gwt client so I need your help

Any useful comment is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [inline-images](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/), for example:

```
data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>

<img src="data:<mime-type>;base64,<yourBase64Data>" width="16"  height="16"/>
```

However according to the RFC, there are size limitations for inline images. Browsers are only required to support URLs up to 1,024 bytes in length. IE 5-7 does not support Inline images.

In IE8 or later version of IE `data protocol` is supported: [msdn:Data Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Emm... The thing is the byte array is comming from decoded base64 string; So the thing is IE8 doesn't support base64 images so is there a way to convert base64 to binary right on GWT client?

Comment: I mean can base64 be converted to binary right on the client?